# App Store Newbie Needing Advice

Tags: ios, app-store

I have developed a hybrid app that is running really well on cocoon.js
The next step is to deploy the app for my client and therein lies my problem.

They want to privately upload the app to the Apples App Store - where only they can access it. Is this possible? Private app? and will it still be scrutinized by apple before they allow it on the app store?

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question within the scope defined in the [help]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about usage of App Store, not programming. See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165/1402846

Answer (score 0):

I think what they want to do is that they don't want to share their iTunesConnect with you, is that right?

This will not work, you have to upload the binary with Xcode or Apple's ApplicationLoader. Of course, even if they upload the build Apple will still check whether the binary is valid, fulfills all the requirements and does not conflict with their guidelines. What you can do is to set the release to *Developer Release* so they can finally decide when to publish the app.

Hope that helps you :)